# Buildozer error while compiling

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, compilation, kivy

I'm running buildozer on Ubuntu 64 14.04 on VirtualBox:

`buildozer android debug deploy run`

And I have following error and I can't find out the cause of it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.16-dev', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 959, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 85, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 97, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 193, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 467, in build_package
    version = self.buildozer.get_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 656, in get_version
    version = match.groups()[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

In **buildozer.spec**:

`version.regex = __version__ = '0.0.1'`

In **main.py**:

`__version__ = '0.0.1'`

**UPDATE:**

Another error:

```
# Package the application
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python2.7 build.py --name Mathcore --version 0.0.1 --package org.test.mathcore --private /home/necronomicron/Code/Mathcore/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation landscape debug
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're setting the version in the buildozer.spec anyway, try commenting out the version.regex and version.filename lines, and use `version = 1.2.0` directly.

Comment: Paste the full log as a new question, running with --verbose.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447792/buildozer-error-calledprocesserror-kivy

Comment: Must it be exactly 1.2.0 or any? If it is, version of what is it?

Comment: If you set the version directly, it can be anything.