# Buildozer error, CalledProcessError (Kivy)

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, ubuntu, kivy

I have following error while running `buildozer android debug deploy run` (Ubuntu 64 14.04 on VirtualBox):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 491, in <module>
    make_package(args)
  File "build.py", line 354, in make_package
    subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python2.7 build.py --name Mathcore --version 0.0.1 --package org.test.mathcore --private /home/necronomicron/Code/Mathcore/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation landscape debug
```

Although I've found [this](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/101), and it says it's closed. Also I am new to Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `buildozer --verbose android debug` and paste the full output. Though at a guess, this is because you lack 32 bit libraries. If so, you need something like

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get -qqy update
sudo apt-get -qqy install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

If this doesn't work, you should look for the right way to install these packages in your version of ubuntu, I don't remember what version this example is for.

Comment: Thank you, it successfully packs now.